# SQL Server - how to select x number of task per x number of workers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help writing a query in SQL Server 2012 to select a specific number of tasks per a selected number of workers. If I was doing something like this is a traditional programming language I would use something like a foreach. However I can't find a nice way to implement a foreach function into sql. I'm sure there is a simpler way to do this.

For example, lets say I have 3 tables:

### **MonthlyReview**

DateReviewed,
WorkerID

### **Workers**

WorkerID,
WorkerName

### **Tasks**

TaskID,
WorkerID

First I select the workers I want to be selecting from (they are filtered on some other data such as name or org (not pictured)) so I thought it would make things easier to put it in a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #WorkersToAudit (
WorkerID varchar(45),
DateReviewed datetime)

INSERT INTO #WorkersToAudit(WorkerID, DateReviewed)
SELECT TOP (4) Workers.WorkerID, MIN(MonthlyReview.DateReviewed) AS DateReviewed FROM Workers
LEFT JOIN MonthlyReview ON Workers.WorkerID = MonthlyReview.WorkerID 
WHERE Workers.WorkerName LIKE '%Browne%'
GROUP BY Worker.WorkerID

    DROP TABLE #WorkersToAudit
```

I was thinking I could then grab the (4) WokerID's in the results and find (4) TaskID's for each, but I haven't found a nice way to do this despite a lot of searching. The number of WorkerID's searched for and the number of TraderID's returned for each one can be anywhere from 1-10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in one query is to use WINDOWING functions.  In this case `ROW_NUMBER()` will work:

```
select WorkerID, TaskID
FROM (
    SELECT Workers.WorkerID, Tasks.TaskID, 
        row_number() over (partition by Workers.WorkerID order by Tasks.TaskID) AS rn
    FROM Workers
    LEFT JOIN Tasks ON Workers.WorkerID = Tasks.WorkerID 
    WHERE Workers.WorkerName LIKE '%Browne%'
) where rn <= 4
```

Notice the key parts of the `over` clause of the `row_number()` function - the `partition by` essentially "groups" the counting of rows by WorkerID, and the `order by` specifies, well, the ordering of rows that are counted.

You can change how the row_number does its grouping and ordering, and you can include whatever columns you want in the `select` clause, but the key part is indeed the use of the `row_number()` function itself.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this! I'll give it a try and report back.